# for の中で if と continue を動作させたいです。

Tags: python, python3

先月からPython3の勉強を始めた初心者です。

現在サイコロを振るプログラムを作っているのですが、
その中でうまく動作の繰り返しを行うことができず悩んでいます。

下のようなコードなのですが、diceQ にどんな文字を入力しても
else以下が3回繰り返されてしまいます。

```
import random

dice = random.randint(1, 6)     # random.randintで6面サイコロ


diceQ = input("サイコロを振りますか？ : ")  # yesかnoの選択
for diceQ in "yes":
    if diceQ == "yes":
        print("結果が出ます。。。")
        print("[ ", dice, " ]が出ました。")   # 結果が出た後 diceQ に戻りたい
        continue
    elif diceQ == "no":
        print("プログラムを終了します")    # ここで終わる
    else:
        print("「yes」か「no」で答えてくださいッ！")   # この後も diceQ に戻りたい
        continue
```

for以外にwhileで考えてはみたのですが、それらしきものはわかりませんでした。
for diceQ in "yes": の下りがおかしいのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: コードの先頭に4つスペースで字下げする （入力画面で `{}` 押したらいいです）ことでコードとして表示できるのでまずそれで質問を編集して，お手元のコードと同じ表示になったかどうか確認してください ( [Markdown ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) も参照ください）．

Comment: そ、それは`yes`が3文字だから……。`for diceQ in "yes":`がやっているのは`yes`の先頭から一文字ずつ`diceQ`に入れて反復処理してるだけです。Pythonには公式のすぐれたチュートリアルがあるのでまずはそれをやってはどうでしょうか https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: [これ](https://trinket.io/python3/c2a7cd2fda) を確認してみて下さい。

Comment: @CrosbyBob Python の基本的な文法に誤解があるようですので、何か一冊 Python 入門の本を読んで、まとまった知識を得るのが近道かもしれません。

Comment: 皆さん丁寧に答えてくださってくれてありがとうございます。公式チュートリアル、教本を確認してきます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**原因**
`for diceQ in "yes":`の部分が少なくともおかしいと思います。
この処理の意味は、"yes"を一文字ずつ処理するという意味です。
diceQには、順に"y","e","s"と入れられ、ループに入るので、
３回処理されるわけです。"y","e","s"は、どれも"yes"でもなく、
"no"でもないので、**３回**、"yes"か"no"でこたえてくださいという
処理に振り分けられてしまうのです。

for文は、最初にどのようなシーケンスを定めるかで、処理の回数が決まってしまうと言っていいです。つまり、有限回数のループを行うという点が、while文と違います。
そのため、無限ループという表現は、while文の説明でよくなされます。
**シーケンスとは**
シーケンスとは、要素を一つずつ取り出すことのできる連続したデータの事を言います。
[1,2,3]などのリストや(1,2,3)のタプルはもちろん、"あいう"などの文字列もシーケンスとなります。他にもありますが、ここでは詳しく書きません。
連続したデータと書きましたが、[1]だと動かないというわけではありません。

ユーザーの入力によって、処理が終了するか、継続するかが問われていますから、while文によるのがいいでしょう。
for文だと、ユーザーの意志ではなく、シーケンスがすべて取り出されるか否かで終了するか否かでユーザーの意志にかかわらず終了してしまうため、ユーザーの意志に処理の継続をかかわらせているこのコードとは、親和性が無いと思います。おそらく質問者様の意図に沿わない結果になりそうです。
**代替案**
出来合いの物ですが、これを試してみてください。

```
import random
diceQ = ""

while True:
    if diceQ =="":
        diceQ = input("サイコロを振りますか？ : ") 
    elif diceQ == "yes":
        dice = random.randint(1, 6)     # random.randintで6面サイコロ
        print("結果が出ます。。。")
        print("[ ", dice, " ]が出ました。")   # 結果が出た後 diceQ に戻りたい
        diceQ = ""#その都度、diceQを初期化
    elif diceQ == "no":
        print("プログラムを終了します")
        break
    else:
        if diceQ != "":
            print("「yes」か「no」で答えてくださいッ！") 
            diceQ = "" #その都度、diceQを初期化`コードをここに入力
```

`

これだと、思ったような動作をされるのではないでしょうか？
**continue文**
`continue`はループ処理でループの最初に戻るということのようで、
while文でもfor文でも使えるようです。
私のコードより別解答の方のコードの方が`continue`を利用している美しい答案だと思います。

**random.randintの注意点**
それと、`random.randint`の使い方ですが、これは、最初に変数に入れてしまうと、もう、その最初に入れた変数で固定化してしまいます。ループにいれて、その都度変数に入れなおさないと、別々の数字ではなく、常に同じ数字が出てくることになります。
もしよろしければ、`random.randoint(1,6)`をループの外に出して、処理の違いを確認してみてください。

Comment: 細かく説明してくださりありがたいです。とても参考になりました。Pythonについてもっと勉強しなおしてきます。

Answer (score 2):

`for diceQ in yes`
としてしまうと、diceQには、`y`と`e`と`s`が1回ずつ入ってしまいます。
そうなると`"y" == "yes"`、`"e" == "yes"`、`"s" == "yes"`となり絶対に条件がTrueになりません。
そのため、else節が3回実行されています。

下の例のように変えてみてください

```
import random


while True: # whileを使う 
    diceQ = input("サイコロを振りますか？ : ")  # yesかnoの選択
    if diceQ == "yes":
        dice = random.randint(1, 6)    # random.randintで6面サイコロ
        print("結果が出ます。。。")
        print("[ ", dice, " ]が出ました。")
        continue # whileの最初に戻る
    elif diceQ == "no":
        print("プログラムを終了します")
        break # whileから抜ける
    else:
        print("「yes」か「no」で答えてくださいッ！")   # この後も diceQ に戻りたい
        continue
```

Comment: forについて大きな誤解をしていたようです。基本をしっかり勉強しなおします。わかりやすい説明ありがとうございます。